# Elastic Search multi match gets wrong result

Tags: java, jquery, json, elasticsearch

I am sending a query to Elastic Search to find all segments which has a field matching the query.
We are implementing a "free search" which the user could write any text he wants and we build a query which search this text throw all the segments fields.
Each segment which one (or more) of it's fields has this text should return

For example:

I would like to get all the segments which with the name "tony lopez".
Each segment has a field of "first_name" and a field of "last_name".

The query our service builds:

```
  "multi_match" : {
    "query": "tony lopez",
    "type": "best_fields"
    "fields": [],
    "operator": "OR"
  }
```

The result from the Elastic using this query is a segment which includes "first_name" field "tony" and "last_name" field "lopez", but also a segment when the "first_name" field is "joe" and "last_name" is "tony".

In this type of query, I would like to recive only the segments which it's name is "tony (first_name) lopez (last_name)"

How can I fix that issue?

Comment: It is always better to add more context to the question. Would be great if you specify the mapping and some sample data

Comment: What's  the correct result?

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

Each field mentioned data type is "text".

We implemented a "free search", which you can insert any text and recive the segments which this text found in one of their fields.

the correct result is only the segments which the first name is "tony" and the last name is "lopez".

Answer (score 2):

Hope i'm not jumping into conclusions too soon but if you want to get only `tony` and `lopez` as firstname and lastname use this:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": { 
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       {
         "match": {
           "first": "tony"
         }
       },
       {
         "match": {
           "last": "lopez"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
  }
}
```

But if one of your indexed documents contains for example `tony s` as firstname, the query above will return it too.

Why? `firstname` is a `text` datatype

> A field to index full-text values, such as the body of an email or the description of a product. These fields are analyzed, that is they are passed through an analyzer to convert the string into a list of individual terms before being indexed.

[More Details](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html)

If you run this query via `kibana`:

```
POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "field": "first", 
  "text": ["tony s"]
}
```

You will see that `tony s` is analyzed as two tokens `tony` and `s`.

> passed through an analyzer to convert the string into a list of individual terms (tony as a term and s as a term).

That is why the above query returns `tony s` in results, it matches `tony`.

If you want to get only `tony` and `lopez` exact match then you should use this query:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": { 
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       {
         "term": {
           "first.keyword": {
             "value": "tony"
           }
         }
       },
       {
         "term": {
           "last.keyword": {
             "value": "lopez"
           }
         }
       }
     ]
   }
  }
}
```

[Read about keyword datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html)

**UPDATE**

Try this query - it is not perfect same issue with my `tony s` example and if you have a document with firstname `lopez` and lastname `tony` it will find it.

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": { 
   "multi_match": {
     "query": "tony lopez",
     "fields": [],
     "type": "cross_fields",
     "operator":"AND",
     "analyzer":   "standard"

   }
  }
}
```

> The cross_fields type is particularly useful with structured documents where multiple fields should match. For instance, when querying the first_name and last_name fields for “Will Smith”, the best match is likely to have “Will” in one field and “Smith” in the other

[cross fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

As good as your suggestoin, we are implementing a "free search", which you can insert any text and recive the segments which this text found in one of their fields.

Therefore, my query to the elastic is just the query itself, without specify which fields I am searching.

I will edit my question and add this critical information.

Comment: @RoyLeibovitz check out my update - scroll down till you see **UPDATE**

Comment: The problem with the lastest solution is that the first name and last name fields are seperate into 2 diffrent fields. 
Therefore, when I send this query I am getting 0 results..

Comment: I don't understand. please share your mappings.

Comment: "firstName":{
      "type":"keyword", "fields" :{
        "ngram" :{
          "type":"text",
          "analyzer":"my_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer":"standard"
        }
      }
    },
"lastName":{
      "type":"keyword", "fields" :{
        "ngram" :{
          "type":"text",
          "analyzer":"my_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer":"standard"
        }
      }
    }

Comment: @RoyLeibovitz i just saw that you are using a custom analyzer, cross_fields treats fields with the same analyzer as though they were one big field. i updated my query (added **"analyzer":   "standard"**) so the query will apply the same analyzer on all fields.